# Is it possible to Add labels/Views out of UICollectionViewCell bounds?If yes then how?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uicollectionview

I have the below UI design and I am 90% done where I have sticky header , different types of collectionViewCells but got struck in how to add a UILabel View outside the CollectionViewCell bounds(Time Label).Is its possible to achieve?If yes please suggest.

[image]

I checked in few places on how to have outof bound collectionviewcell but did proper answer.

Few think which strike me was

1. To create a Cell full width and achieve it and add the UILable Inside the Cell View but its a workaround .
2. Add one more view on top of CollectionView but the problem is while scrolling there will be overhead and performance issues.

Let me know is there anyway to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for checking this , but Got the Answer and its really simple

cell.clipsToBounds = NO;

Thats it :)